# Yii: how to perform db migration on test database?

Tags: unit-testing, migration, yii, database-migration

Is there a command that performs migrations on test database in Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, no.
But you can change your database connection in config/console.php and run it on another database.

Comment: Not true anymore, see Eric's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you just change the connectionID to point to your testdb. So, in config/main.php you just add:

```
'components'=>...
    'testdb'=>array(
      'class'=>'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_test_db',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'myuser',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        );
...
```

Notice the property in that array.

Once you have that, you can run migrations by writing to terminal:

```
protected/yiic migrate --connectionID=testdb
```

Comment: Is there any way to include that in the initialization of my test cases, so it's getting executed automatically?

Comment: Keep in mind that there could be code in migration which uses Yii::app()->db. Took me some time to understand why a migration which uses the DbAuthmanager component failed for my test db...
Since the migration command is a console command, shouldnt it be config/console.php to add the testdb component?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically if you're using codeception you can use

> php codeception/bin/yii migrate/up --interactive=0

from inside the tests folder

Answer (score 0):

For the current yii2 version, I happen to use

```
php test/bin/yii migrate
```

And my database configurations are in `config/test_db.php`